# formatting bigdecimal numbers after operating

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I'm trying to sort BigDecimal numbers. here is the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = scan.nextInt();
    List<BigDecimal> hs = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        BigDecimal b = scan.nextBigDecimal();
        hs.add(b);
    }
    Collections.sort(hs, Collections.reverseOrder());
    for (int i = 0; i < hs.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(hs.get(i));
    }
}
```

It's working fine but when I give input like this.

```
5
50
.325
.324
-5
100
```

Output:

```
100
50
0.325
0.324
-5
```

I am not able to catch why this .325 is converting to 0.325, how can I remove this?

Comment: The sorting appears correct from largest to smallest.  Is your question a formatting issue or is there something else?

Comment: `.325` is mathematically identical to `0.325`. Is your question about the formatting of the output, or do you expect a different order? If so - what?

Comment: There are many ways of writing 0.325 - do you think that .325 is much diffrent from 0.325?

Comment: yes formatting issue, I don't want this 0 to be added before point value, like I gave input .325 and it returns 0.325, don't need this 0 to be added

Comment: @Atul Your question's title and the sorting code are rather misleading when your *actual* question is about how to specify a particular format when printing a BigDecimal.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should be going with @rgettman 's solution of using `DecimalFormat`, but this is a *possible* alternative:

```
Collections.sort(hs, Collections.reverseOrder());
for (int i=0; i < hs.size(); i++) {
    // conditionally remove a leading zero
    String value = hs.get(i).toString().replaceFirst("^(-?)0\\.", "$1.");
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Comment: yes value = value.replaceFirst("^0\\.", "."); this is working fine

Comment: So what about -0.325? Do you want this to be "-.325", which would only be consistent, but that doesn't work with this solution.

Comment: yes "-.325" should be -.325, it's not working in this case, right

Comment: I updated my answer to handle the case of the negative.  If your formatting requirements are complex, then you should consider using `DecimalFormat`, but my answer is a way to do without this, at least for a simple use case.

Comment: Why not `hs.get(i).toString().replaceFirst("^(-?)0\\.", "$1.");`? A single replacement call is enough.